# Powershell -like operator not giving results

Tags: powershell

Trying to check weather a software is installed in my system or not using this pretty simple script.

```
$ltc = @('Microsoft Office','Python','Google Chrome')
$InstalledSoftware = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
foreach($obj in $InstalledSoftware) {
        $name = $obj.GetValue('DisplayName')
        #write-host $name
        foreach($lt in $ltc){
                if($name -like $lt) {
                    write-host $obj.GetValue('DisplayName') -NoNewline; write-host " - " -NoNewline; write-host $obj.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
        }
    }
}
timeout 60
```

For some reason, it only matches `Google Chrome` and not the other two. I have both Office and Python installed. Not sure where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `$name -like "*$lt*"`? `-like` performs an exact match unless you provide it with wildcards

Comment: You can also do `get-package *office*,*python*,*chrome*`

Comment: @js2010 trouble is it also gets all the Updates as Programs. For python it returns 5 values, interpreter, utility scripts, standard libraries etc etc

Comment: You can get more specific with office, like `get-package 'microsoft office professional*' -Provider msi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your original code you really want to use the -contains operator vs the -like operator.

```
Clear-Host

$ltc = @('Microsoft 365 - en-us','SharpKeys','Microsoft Visual Studio Code')
$InstalledSoftware = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
foreach($obj in $InstalledSoftware) {
        $name = $obj.GetValue('DisplayName')
       # write-host $name
         if($ltc -contains $name) {
           "$($obj.GetValue('DisplayName')) - $($obj.GetValue('DisplayVersion'))"
        }
}
```

Sample Output using programs on my computer:

```
Microsoft 365 - en-us - 16.0.15427.20210
SharpKeys - 3.9.2000
Microsoft Visual Studio Code - 1.70.2
```

I also modified your output statement to make it simpler.